# VSTS Deploy Test Agent Warning: 'Failed to start service VisualStudioRemoteDeployer'

Tags: automated-tests, agent, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to run automated coded UI/selenium tests on a virtual machine through VSTS. The test assemblies are successfully copied over to the virtual machine.

However, when I use the "Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment" task, I am receiving this series of errors:

```
2018-04-26T23:56:18.0956226Z testMachineInput         = SIT-WEB.corp.com
2018-04-26T23:56:18.1112475Z adminUserName            = AMR\abbie
2018-04-26T23:56:18.1112475Z winRmProtocal            = Http
2018-04-26T23:56:18.1112475Z testCertificate          = true
2018-04-26T23:56:18.1112475Z machineUserName          =
2018-04-26T23:56:18.1112475Z runAsProcess             = true
2018-04-26T23:56:18.1112475Z logonAutomatically       = true
2018-04-26T23:56:18.1112475Z disableScreenSaver       = true
2018-04-26T23:56:18.1112475Z isDataCollectionOnly     = false
2018-04-26T23:56:18.1112475Z testPlatform             = 15.0
2018-04-26T23:56:18.1112475Z agentLocation            = 
2018-04-26T23:56:18.1112475Z updateTestAgent          = false
2018-04-26T23:56:18.1112475Z ****************************************************************
2018-04-26T23:56:18.6112524Z Starting to deploy and configure test agent on test machines.
2018-04-26T23:56:18.6112524Z Inputs provided are:
2018-04-26T23:56:18.6112524Z Use HTTP Port: True
2018-04-26T23:56:18.6112524Z Username: AMR\abbie
2018-04-26T23:56:18.6112524Z Disable Screen saver: True
2018-04-26T23:56:18.6112524Z Login Automatically: True
2018-04-26T23:56:18.6112524Z Run as process: True
2018-04-26T23:56:18.6112524Z Agent would be downloaded from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615472
2018-04-26T23:56:18.6112524Z Update test agent: False
2018-04-26T23:56:18.6112524Z Run test agent as DataCollection only : False
2018-04-26T23:56:19.0643890Z Task 'VerifyTestAgentInstalled' on machine 'SIT-WEB.corp.com:5985' is being run
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7831688Z Task 'VerifyTestAgentInstalled' on machine 'SIT-WEB.amr.corp.com:5985' completed.
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7831688Z ##[warning]Task 'VerifyTestAgentInstalled' for machine SIT-WEB.com:5985's Error : System.AggregateException: Failed to start service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097'. Consult the logs below:
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7831688Z Service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097 (VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097 on computer '.'.
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7831688Z  CategoryInfo :OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7831688Z  FullyQualifiedErrorId :CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7831688Z  ---> System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097 (VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097 on computer '.'.
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7831688Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7831688Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.Invoke(String errorContextMessage, Boolean writeResultToLog, Boolean isCancellable) in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\DevTestLabs\Client\Deployment\Deployment\PowershellExecutor.cs:line 178
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7831688Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.RemoteDeploymentHelper.StartService(String serviceName) in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\DevTestLabs\Client\Deployment\Deployment\RemoteDeploymentHelper.cs:line 97
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7831688Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.DeploymentClient.<RunAsync>d__24.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\DevTestLabs\Client\Deployment\Deployment\DeploymentClient.cs:line 367
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7987958Z ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097 (VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097 on computer '.'.<---
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7987958Z 
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7987958Z ##[warning]Task 'VerifyTestAgentInstalled' for machine SIT-WEB.corp.com:5985's Log : System.AggregateException: Failed to start service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097'. Consult the logs below:
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7987958Z Service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097 (VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097 on computer '.'.
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7987958Z  CategoryInfo :OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7987958Z  FullyQualifiedErrorId :CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7987958Z  ---> System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097 (VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097 on computer '.'.
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7987958Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7987958Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.Invoke(String errorContextMessage, Boolean writeResultToLog, Boolean isCancellable) in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\DevTestLabs\Client\Deployment\Deployment\PowershellExecutor.cs:line 178
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7987958Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.RemoteDeploymentHelper.StartService(String serviceName) in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\DevTestLabs\Client\Deployment\Deployment\RemoteDeploymentHelper.cs:line 97
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7987958Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.DeploymentClient.<RunAsync>d__24.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\DevTestLabs\Client\Deployment\Deployment\DeploymentClient.cs:line 367
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7987958Z ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097 (VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097 on computer '.'.<---
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7987958Z 
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7987958Z ##[error]Error occurred on 'SIT-WEB.com:5985'. Details : 'Failed to start service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097'. Consult the logs below:
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7987958Z Service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097 (VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097 on computer '.'.
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7987958Z  CategoryInfo :OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7987958Z  FullyQualifiedErrorId :CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7987958Z '. For troubleshooting, refer https://aka.ms/remotevstest.
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7987958Z Service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097 (VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097 on computer '.'.
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7987958Z  CategoryInfo :OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7987958Z  FullyQualifiedErrorId :CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
2018-04-26T23:56:22.7987958Z '. For troubleshooting, refer https://aka.ms/remotevstest.
2018-04-26T23:56:22.8769311Z ##[error]Exception calling "Start" with "1" argument(s): "Deploy Test Agent task has failed on all machines. Check the logs for more details."
2018-04-26T23:56:22.9081625Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy TestAgent on
```

I realize that this is the deprecated series of test tasks, but we are having trouble actually getting the newer version to work with a hosted agent because UNC paths are not accepted as search folder options.

Update:

After downloading the test agent to my machine, I am getting a new set of errors:
Below are my build definitions as well as my new error log.
[Copy definition/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/to2KE.png)  [Deploy Test Agent definition/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA02f.png)  [Run Test Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGycG.png)

```
    2018-05-10T17:01:30.1946693Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy TestAgent on SIT-WEB.com
2018-05-10T17:01:30.1960462Z ==============================================================================
2018-05-10T17:01:30.1960794Z Task         : Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment
2018-05-10T17:01:30.1961001Z Description  : Deploy and configure Test Agent to run tests on a set of machines
2018-05-10T17:01:30.1961202Z Version      : 1.0.42
2018-05-10T17:01:30.1961369Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-05-10T17:01:30.1961552Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=625976)
2018-05-10T17:01:30.1961751Z ==============================================================================
2018-05-10T17:01:30.2036732Z Preparing task execution handler.
2018-05-10T17:01:31.1771823Z Executing the powershell script: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\agent\_work\_tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent_52a38a6a-1517-41d7-96cc-73ee0c60d2b6\1.0.42\DeployTestAgent.ps1
2018-05-10T17:01:33.3696416Z ##[error]Unable to process command '##vso[task.setvariable variable=DTA:cd7fb3c2-465a-40d0-9cae-b9fa87fc4215;issecret=true;]{"TestMachineProps":{"_machinePropertyMap":{"dta://env/Cut/_apis/3117/201805101001333378":"Microsoft-AgentsForVS"}},"TestUriDetails":{"_environmentMap":{"dta://env/Cut/_apis/3117/201805101001333378":"SIT-WEB.com"}},"TestDeploymentEnvDetails":{"_testEnvironmentMap":{"SIT-WEB.com":{"Id":0,"Url":null,"Revision":0,"Project":{"Id":"Cut","Name":"Cut"},"ModifiedBy":{"Name":"7e665146-2d3c-6194-8b85-fa4143db4342"},"Resources":[{"Id":1,"Name":"SIT-WEB.com","Properties": {%0D%0A              "Microsoft-Vslabs-MG-Resource-FQDN": {%0D%0A                "IsSecure": false,%0D%0A                "Data": "SIT-WEB.com"%0D%0A              },%0D%0A              "WinRM_Http": {%0D%0A                "IsSecure": false,%0D%0A                "Data": "5985"%0D%0A              }%0D%0A            }%0D%0A          }%0D%0A        ],%0D%0A        "Properties": {%0D%0A          "Microsoft-Vslabs-MG-Resource-Username": {%0D%0A            "IsSecure": false,%0D%0A            "Data": "AMR\\abbiejon"%0D%0A          },%0D%0A          "Microsoft-Vslabs-MG-Resource-Password": {%0D%0A            "IsSecure": true,%0D%0A            "Data": "***"%0D%0A          },%0D%0A          "Microsoft-Vslabs-MG-WinRMProtocol": {%0D%0A            "IsSecure": false,%0D%0A            "Data": "HTTP"%0D%0A          },%0D%0A          "Microsoft-Vslabs-MG-SkipCACheck": {%0D%0A            "IsSecure": false,%0D%0A            "Data": "False"%0D%0A          }%0D%0A        },%0D%0A        "Name": "SIT-WEB.com",%0D%0A        "IsReserved": false,%0D%0A        "CreatedBy": {%0D%0A          "Name": "7e665146-2d3c-6194-8b85-fa4143db4342"%0D%0A        },%0D%0A        "CreatedDate": "2018-05-10T17:01:33.2753626Z",%0D%0A        "ModifiedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"%0D%0A      }%0D%0A    }%0D%0A  }%0D%0A}' successfully. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2018-05-10T17:01:33.3710621Z ##[error]Secrets cannot contain multiple lines
2018-05-10T17:01:33.8621018Z DistributedTests: Starting to deploy and configure test agent on test machines.
2018-05-10T17:01:33.8621317Z DistributedTests: Inputs provided are:
2018-05-10T17:01:33.8621502Z DistributedTests: Username: AMR\abbiejon
2018-05-10T17:01:33.8621986Z DistributedTests: Use HTTP Port: True
2018-05-10T17:01:33.8622157Z DistributedTests: Run as process: True
2018-05-10T17:01:33.8622342Z DistributedTests: Login Automatically: True
2018-05-10T17:01:33.8622514Z DistributedTests: Disable Screen saver: True
2018-05-10T17:01:33.8622716Z DistributedTests: Agent would be downloaded from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615472
2018-05-10T17:01:33.8622924Z DistributedTests: Update test agent: False
2018-05-10T17:01:33.8623105Z DistributedTests: Run test agent as DataCollection only : False
2018-05-10T17:01:33.8623393Z DistributedTests: Path to script that installs test agent on remote machine: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\agent\_work\_tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent_52a38a6a-1517-41d7-96cc-73ee0c60d2b6\1.0.42\TestAgentInstall.ps1
2018-05-10T17:01:33.8625199Z DistributedTests: Path to script that configures test agent on remote machine: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\agent\_work\_tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent_52a38a6a-1517-41d7-96cc-73ee0c60d2b6\1.0.42\TestAgentConfiguration.ps1
2018-05-10T17:01:33.8625606Z DistributedTests: Path to script that downloads test agent on Azure remote machines : C:\Windows\SysWOW64\agent\_work\_tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent_52a38a6a-1517-41d7-96cc-73ee0c60d2b6\1.0.42\DownloadTestAgent.ps1
2018-05-10T17:01:33.8625995Z DistributedTests: Path to script that checks if test agent is installed on remote machine: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\agent\_work\_tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent_52a38a6a-1517-41d7-96cc-73ee0c60d2b6\1.0.42\CheckTestAgentInstallation.ps1
2018-05-10T17:01:33.8626400Z DistributedTests: Path to script that checks if test agent is already running on remote machine: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\agent\_work\_tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent_52a38a6a-1517-41d7-96cc-73ee0c60d2b6\1.0.42\VerifyTestMachinesAreInUse.ps1
2018-05-10T17:01:33.8626713Z DistributedTests: Path to script that helps to download and configure test agent : 
2018-05-10T17:01:33.8626951Z DistributedTests: Task 'PopulatingMachinesPresentState' on machine 'SIT-WEB.com:5985' is being run
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3156824Z DistributedTests: Task 'PopulatingMachinesPresentState' on machine 'SIT-WEB.com:5985' completed.
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3209546Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Task 'PopulatingMachinesPresentState' for machine SIT-WEB.com:5985's Error : System.AggregateException: Failed to start service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff'. Consult the logs below:
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3210707Z Service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff (VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff on computer '.'.
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3213811Z  CategoryInfo :OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3214259Z  FullyQualifiedErrorId :CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3214742Z  ---> System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff (VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff on computer '.'.
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3215153Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3215626Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.Invoke(String errorContextMessage, Boolean writeResultToLog, Boolean isCancellable)
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3216024Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.RemoteDeploymentHelper.StartService(String serviceName)
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3216698Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.DeploymentClient.<RunAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3218150Z ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff (VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff on computer '.'.<---
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3218472Z 
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3219184Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Task 'PopulatingMachinesPresentState' for machine SIT-WEB.com:5985's Log : System.AggregateException: Failed to start service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff'. Consult the logs below:
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3221150Z Service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff (VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff on computer '.'.
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3221658Z  CategoryInfo :OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3222157Z  FullyQualifiedErrorId :CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3222701Z  ---> System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff (VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff on computer '.'.
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3223208Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3223659Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.Invoke(String errorContextMessage, Boolean writeResultToLog, Boolean isCancellable)
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3224196Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.RemoteDeploymentHelper.StartService(String serviceName)
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3224645Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.DeploymentClient.<RunAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3225206Z ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff (VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff on computer '.'.<---
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3225684Z 
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3226401Z ##[error]Error occurred on 'SIT-WEB.com:5985'. Details : 'Failed to start service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff'. Consult the logs below:
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3228948Z Service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff (VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff on computer '.'.
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3229455Z  CategoryInfo :OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3229893Z  FullyQualifiedErrorId :CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3231484Z '. For troubleshooting, refer https://aka.ms/remotevstest.
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3240548Z ##[error]System.Exception: Error occurred on 'SIT-WEB.com:5985'. Details : 'Failed to start service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff'. Consult the logs below:
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3241695Z Service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff (VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service VisualStudioRemoteDeployer08bb67c0-170e-4bd9-9d07-094bbf5cacff on computer '.'.
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3242509Z  CategoryInfo :OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3242924Z  FullyQualifiedErrorId :CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3243296Z '. For troubleshooting, refer https://aka.ms/remotevstest.
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3728128Z DistributedTests: Update test agent is disabled. Skipping test agent updates.
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3773380Z ##[warning]For troubleshooting, refer https://aka.ms/remotevstest.
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3785766Z ##[error]System.InvalidOperationException: Deploy Test Agent task has failed on all machines. Check the logs for more details.
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3786705Z    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DistributedTestAutomation.DtlMachineDeploymentHelper.ThrowIfNumberOfTargetMachinesAreZero(String exceptionMessage)
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3787228Z    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DistributedTestAutomation.DtlMachineDeploymentHelper.ConfigureTestAgent(String username, String password, String collectionUrl, Boolean runAsProcess, Boolean disableScreenSaver, Boolean logonAutomatically, String environmentUrl, String configureTestAgentScriptPath, String personalAccessToken, String capabilities, List`1 machinesToBeExcluded, Boolean keepConnectionAlive)
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3787696Z    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DistributedTestAutomation.DeployTestAgent.Run()
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3787980Z    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DistributedTestAutomation.TaskRunner.Run(Dictionary`2 arguments, VssConnection connection, TaskType taskType)
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3788286Z    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DistributedTestAutomation.InvokeDeployTestAgentCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3978130Z ##[error]PowerShell script completed with 2 errors.
2018-05-10T17:01:35.3987644Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy TestAgent on SIT-WEB.com


Any insight into what could be causing this error?

Thanks!
```

Comment: Does the account you're using have appropriate administrative access to the machine in question?

Comment: @DanielMann yes, the account does have access. The file copying task works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Task `Deploy Visual Studio Test Agent Task` requires:

- .NET 4.6.1 on Windows7 or Windows 2K8R2
- PowerShell 3 or newer
- Test machines should have PSRemoting enabled (run 'Enable-PSRemoting'
  on Windows Powershell)

You need to check whether your environment meets the requirement.

Comment: All three of these requirements are met. The VMs run Windows 10 and Powershell 5.

Comment: Are you able to start the service 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd538408c-9353-4a01-9acc-e8df4acf2097' manually on your target machine? Try to delete this service, to see whether the issue can be fixed: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dc04a8e2-1711-448d-a14b-85fd232eba36/visualstudioremotedeployer-service?forum=tfsbuild

Comment: It doesn't appear that this service exists on my machine...my understanding is that it should install and remove this visualstudioremotedeployer.exe immediately after finishing

Comment: Are you able to deploy the VS test agent manually on your target machine?

Comment: I manually deployed the test agent, but now I am getting a different type of error: 2018-05-07T21:22:52.0754787Z ##[error]An exception occurred while executing the task. So the task is not executed. 
2018-05-07T21:22:52.1125441Z ##[error]The slice of type 'Execution' is 'Aborted' because of the error : System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Are you able share a screenshot of your build definition? And share the entire build log?

Comment: I added the screen shots for my build as well as the error log to my original post. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It seems you are using Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment v1, have you tried v2?

Comment: I tried v2 and I'm getting the same issue about VisualStudioRemoteDeployer failing to start.

Comment: You may try on another machine to see whether you have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a **logon issue** with the admin account running the **VisualStudioRemoteDeployer** service. This will be the same admin account provided in the PowerShell on Target Machines.

When running the PowerShell on Target Machines task it will connect to the remote machine and then proceed with setting up and starting VisualStudioRemoteDeployer as a temporary Windows service with the provided admin account in the PowerShell on Target Machines task before running the provided PowerShell script. So if it fails installing VisualStudioRemoteDeployer as a service, it will tell you that the service wasn't installed. But in your case the service is actually installed and the log is telling us "**Failed to start service**". This means that the service isn't starting and the Powershell on Target Machines will fail.

You can try to setup a random service on the remote machine with the admin account you provided in the PowerShell on Target Machines and try to start it. If this fails then there´s something wrong with the account you provided and you´re more likley to get a better error message from the services.msc than from PowerShell.

Two things you can check that has solved this issue for us when encountering this problem is to check:

- **Is the account allowed to log on as a service**. Check this using
  "Local Security Policy" and navigate to Local Policies -> User Rights
  Assignment here you should check that the account you provided in the
  PowerShell on Target Machines is a part of the "Log on as a service"
  policy and also that your account isn´t a part of the "Deny log on as
  a service" policy.
- **Is there something wrong with the admin account** We´ve    encounterd
  problems with the account being member of over 1000 groups    which
  will make us pass the token size limit making the account    unable
  to logon then you´ll get the "Failed to start service" message    on
  the PowerShell on Target Machines task. Resolve this by removing
  membership in all unnecessary groups. Read more about max token size 
  here
  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/shanecothran/2010/07/16/maxtokensize-and-kerberos-token-bloat/

Hope this helps, might not be the problem in your case but this is how we fixed our problems with "Failed to start service" with the PowerShell on Target Machines task.