# Failed to start service VisualStudioRemoteDeployer

Tags: deployment, devops

We are using on site Dev-Ops and have a similar problem to that described in the link [Example from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50067570/vsts-deploy-test-agent-warning-failed-to-start-service-visualstudioremotedeplo).

But ours is intermittent.

Our environment uses two build and deploy machines, which each deploy machine having two worker agents.

For one of our projects, when it is deployed, we constantly get the error:

*The VisualStudioRemoteDeployerc4d3852f-411b-48ba-97d8-5e09c8d07ce4 service failed to start due to the following error:
%%2*

But here is the rub, not every time. Sometimes the deployment completes without error.

Other projects that use the same deployment machine and the same target server work each and every time without fail.

The deployment log reports  "*The WSMan provider host process did not return a proper response.*" as an error.

Checking the allocated memory, described in [PowerShell Out of Memory](https://www.centrel-solutions.com/media/xiaconfiguration/adminguideweb/PowerShellOutOfMemory.html), to find our set at 2.1 Billion.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting issue that I have uncovered. The source of this problem stems from the interaction of McAfee Endpoint security.

Said antivirus was reporting that when the remote powershell script, using WSMan, was called. McAfee, saw this as a viral payload and canceled the deployment by stopping the service from running and deleting the payload. This has been reported to McAfee as an issue. In the mean time, internal network security settings for McAfee has had to be modified to ignore the processes used by powershell in remote deployment.